# Push a number in useState array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

In a form having multiple checkbox, I want to store the values of the check box in an useState array after clicking submit. Also the user may check/uncheck a check box multiple times before submitting the form. What can be the approach/code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sounds like the stock standard react forms approach.

Comment: i had tried to store the values of checkbox in a separate useState variable initialised to 0,then checked if checkBox1value>0 then setAllcheckbox(old=>{...old,checkBox1value}) similarly checked for the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every checkbox have a "checked" property, so in state you must have an array with all the checked checkboxes.

```
const [selectedCheckboxes, setSelectedCheckboxes] = useState([]);
```

For example you might store also the checkboxes on an array:

```
const checkboxes = [{name: 'cb1', label:'cb1'}, {name: 'cb2', label:'cb3'}, ...];
```

and all of them should have the same onChange method:

```
onCheckBoxChange = (event) => {
const selectedCheckboxes = [...selectedCheckboxes];
const isChecked = selectedCheckboxes.includes(event.target.name);
if (!isChecked) {
  selectedCheckboxes.push(event.target.name);
} else {
  selectedCheckboxes.splice(selectedCheckboxes.indexOf(event.target.name), 1);
}
setSelectedCheckboxes(selectedCheckboxes);
```

};

a common function that verify if a checkbox is checked:

```
isChecked = (cb) => selectedCheckboxes.includes(cb.name);
```

and every checkbox should look like:

```
   <CheckBox
  name={cb.name}
  checked={isChecked(cb)}
  onChange={onCheckBoxChange}
  {...props}
/>
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! I implemented it slightly differently without a Checkbox but with a Pressable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it multiple ways. You can just make `const checkboxOpenArray = []` where you will just store boolean values like `[true, false, false, true]` so later in the code where you probably `.map` through all checkboxes you just check if `checkboxOpenArray[idx]` where `idx` you get from `.map`. If it is true you just set checkbox to true. Same for `onChange` - you just find `idx` in the `checkboxOpenArray` and set it to false or true.